# Creating a PNG IDAT chunk in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, png

I'm trying to manually create a 16 bit greyscale PNG using Node.js, but the IDAT block both "works" (in some viewers) but also doesn't, as the data doesn't look right in viewers where it does load, and Photoshop doesn't like if because of a "bad adaptive filter value". [The  spec isn't super clear](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/#9Filters) on how to indicate "no filtering" so I've got the filter method set to 0 in the `IHDR` chunk, but I can't figure out where in the `IDAT` to indicate that there is no filtering going on.

The code I'm currently using is:

```js
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
import zlib from "zlib";
import crc32 from 'crc/crc32'; // the node-crc library

// string to bytes
function toBytes(v) {
  return v.split(``).map((v) => v.charCodeAt(0));
}

// encode a number as four-byte value
function fourByte(n) {
  return [
      (n & 0xff000000) >> 24,
      (n & 0xff0000) >> 16,
      (n & 0xff00) >> 8,
      n & 0xff,
    ]; 
  };
}

// create a PNG chunk
function makeChunk(type, data = []) {
  const typeBytes = toBytes(type);
  const length = fourByte(data.length);
  const buffer = [...typeBytes, ...data];
  const crc = crc32(buffer);
  return Buffer.from([...length, ...buffer, ...fourByte(crc)]);
}

// create a sample 16 bit pixel raster
const [w, h] = [10, 10];
const pngPixels = new Uint16Array(w * h);
for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    const i = x + y * w;
    pngPixels[i] = i * 100;
  }
}

// PNG preamble
const magic = Buffer.from([137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]);

// header for 16 bit greyscale image
const IHDR = makeChunk(`IHDR`, [
  ...fourByte(w), // width
  ...fourByte(h), // height
  16, // bit depth: 16 bits
  0, // color: greyscale
  0, // compression method, must be 0
  0, // filter method, must be 0
  0, // interlace method: no interlacing
]);

// deflate the pixels and form data chunk
const IDAT = makeChunk(`IDAT`, zlib.deflateSync(pngPixels.buffer, { level: 9 }));

// turn into a file and write to disk.
const pngData = Buffer.concat([magic, IHDR, IDAT, makeChunk(`IEND`)]);
writeFileSync(`test-out.png`, pngData);
```

I'm clearly not storing the fact that filter method 0 should also use filter *type* 0 ("none" filtering), but I can't for the life of me figure out where that information goes. Does anyone know what I missed/where and how I set that?

Comment: According to Figure 18 shown in [Section 7.3 Filtering](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/#7Filtering), it looks like you have to add an extra 0-byte before each scanline.

Comment: Amazing. I still can't find that in the official spec, but you're right, that's exactly what this ancient HTML page says over on https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information seems oddly missing (or just well-hidden) in the official spec, but the ancient spec doc over on https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Filtering explains that the filter byte has to precede each pixel raster's scanline (i.e. each row of pixels), using only the one byte *irrespective* of color depth (so 10 pixels in 16 bit color, comprising 20 bytes, becomes a 21 byte scan line, not a 22 byte scan line).

In this case, that means the updated code looks like:

```js
...

// 16 bit PNG image data must use big endian ordering,
// so we better find out whether we're going to need to
// do some byte reordering later on:
const LITTLE_ENDIAN = Symbol(`little endian`);
const BIG_ENDIAN = Symbol(`big endian`);
const endian = (function checkEndian() {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(2);
  const u8 = new Uint8Array(buf);
  const u16 = new Uint16Array(buf);
  u8.set([0xaa, 0xbb], 0);
  return u16[0] === 0xbbaa ? LITTLE_ENDIAN : BIG_ENDIAN;
})();

...

// Create our sample 16 bit pixel raster again
const [w, h] = [10, 10];
const pngPixels = new Uint16Array(w * h);
for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    const i = x + y * w;
    pngPixels[i] = ((i / 99) * (2 ** 16 - 1)) | 0;
  }
}

// Convert the pixel raster to scan lines that start with
// a zero byte to indicate filter type "none".

// First, convert our 16 bit values to 8 bit values:
const pngPixels8 = new Uint8Array(pngPixels.buffer);

// Then check if we need to do some endian byte swapping:
if (endian === LITTLE_ENDIAN) {
  for (let i = 0, e = pngPixels8.length; i < e; i += 2) {
    let _ = pngPixels8[i];
    pngPixels8[i] = pngPixels8[i + 1];
    pngPixels8[i + 1] = _;
  }
}

// Then create our new filter-byte-padded scanline array:
const filtered = new Uint8Array(pngPixels8.length + h);
for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
  const s = 2 * y * w;
  const d = 1 + y + s;
  filtered.set(pngPixels8.subarray(s, s + 2 * w), d);
}

...

const IDAT = makeChunk(`IDAT`, zlib.deflateSync(filtered, { level: 9 }));

...
```

(Of course, you could do the data type and endian conversion using a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView), too, although in this case because we need to inject 0x00 in so many places, dumb conversion is fine)